# codeigniter 3 showing not found page[.htaccess and robot.txt]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to put robot.txt on my website on godaddy.
I am putting it on root dir.
But i am getting error404 not found
I think it is due to my .htaccess

Htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I also tried to add condition in htaccess, but not helping

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|assets)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Is there any workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this htaccess:

```html
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on                       
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```